# What's the quickest way to periodically export PostgreSQL data to a local file on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, windows

I have access to a PostgreSQL database that I need to get data from for another system. The other system is running Windows 7 and does not (yet?) have PostgreSQL installed.

Ideally, I'd like to have the results of a few queries saved to local text files that I can then parse as needed, but if SQL dumping everything works, I'm fine with that too.

While I have experience with databases and programming, I'm not strong with either Windows or PostgreSQL.

Should I just install PostgreSQL on this Windows machine and use the command line tools that would then be found there to create a batch file? Or is there a better option?

Comment: No need to install Postgres (although that is quite easy). But it's probably the easiest way to get the command line client `psql`. There are many other SQL clients for Postgres. Several of them also support exporting data into different formats: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html) client (I believe it's in the pgAdmin III [install](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin3/release/v1.20.0/win32/)). Add it to your `PATH`.

Put the following in `%appdata%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` (you may need to create that file):

`hostname:port:database:username:password`

In `cmd`:

`psql -c "\copy (select * from foo) to 'fooLocal.txt';" --host $hostname --dbname $dbname --user $username`

then `fooLocal.txt` will be a tab-delimited representation of the output of your query.

`\copy` (as opposed to `COPY`) can copy data from a remote server and doesn't need superuser privileges.

If you want to run that psql command on a schedule, you can use Task Scheduler (GUI) or [`schtasks`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx) (CLI), which is somewhat like `cron` for Windows.

Comment: `schtasks` is just the command line UI for the Scheduled Tasks system. A Windows admin may be much more comfortable setting up the task via the UI. For that matter, I use cron daily and I still like the task scheduler UI on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to copy a result set into a file is through [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

i.e.:

```
COPY (SELECT ...) TO 'filename.csv';
```

To load the data, you can use the FROM clause. This command is Operating System agnostic, as it is a plain formatted text file.

Comment: But that will create the file on the **server** not on the client.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name We really need a *prominent* note in the `COPY` docs that points people at `psql`'s `\copy` command. It's non-obvious to most people (understandably) and not very discoverable. I should send a patch...